# Initialize global variable in Apache server

Tags: c, multithreading, apache, locking, multiprocessing

I have a simple apache web server with a hook function and a handler function.

```
int globalVar1;
int globalVar2;

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{
    globalVar1 = 9; /* or any other value... */

    /* Create a hook in the request handler, so we get called when a request arrives */
    ap_hook_handler(example_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_LAST);
}

static int example_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    printf("globalVar1=%d", globalVar1); /* print 9 */

    globalVar2 = 9; /* or any other value... */

    printf("globalVar2=%d", globalVar2); /* sometimes print 9 and sometimes not - race condition. */

    /* do something... */
    return OK;
}
```

I noticed that when I initialize globalVar1 in the hook, the variable has the same value as I initialized in the hook,
although the hook and the handler are been called on different processes.

**1. what is the reason for that kind of behavior?**

As a result, I decided to move the variable initialization to the handler function (`globalVar2`).
The problem I noticed is happening when the handler gets 2 requests at the same time and therefore the variable is not being initialized correctly.
So if I want to avoid race condition, I need to use lock on the variable initialization, but if I want to use lock, I need to initialize the lock before
and again I have the problem of initialization in multi threaded system.

**2. How can I use lock in this kind of situation?**

By mentioning variable initialization, I mean any initialization, even calling another function to initialize a global struct.
It could be much easier if I could share memory between the two processes (hook and handler), but from the investigation I did - it is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the initialization is done only once in a multithreaded situation, use a function CallOnce, that internally makes sure it is called exactly once.

For example: C11 threads.h [call_once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/call_once), or [pthread_once](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_once.html).

Comment: Does the CallOnce function provide lock until the end of the call? e.g., all other threads will wait until the one thread inside the CallOnce function will finish his running inside the CallOnce function...

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to call the init function again using the call_once function, in case of a failure in the init function?

Comment: Found it! Using try-catch statement. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once